# Стили по умолчанию в GWT приложении

Tags: gwt, java, intellij-idea, css, jetbrains

Создал приложение GWT в Intellij Idea.По умолчанию создался проект содержащий пример кода. Данный пример подхватывал стандартные стили для всех элементов (кнопки, диалоговые окна  и т.д.). После удаления исходного кода и добавления своих классов стили пропали, т.е. я загружаю страничку, а там безликие кнопки. В чем проблема? Может надо прописать дополнительные зависимости?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы модифицировали xml-файл, в котором указывается модуль и зависимые библиотеки, вы могли удалить зависимость от темы. Если Вы не найдете следующей записи в своем файле, добавьте ее и все заработает.

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаком с gwt. Но возможно мой подход вам поможет, создайте ещё раз стандартное приложение и проанализируйте его, возможно, найдете в нем ответ.

Comment: Пробовал неоднократно, результата нет. Кстати, это проявляется и в Eclipse.

Comment: Может пример кода покажите?)

Comment: Кода у меня достаточно много, но данная проблема проявляется даже если после удаления создать лишь одну кнопку. Кнопка на выходе не будет иметь GWT'шных стилей.

Comment: Извините, вы меня не правильно поняли, я просил код который в стандартном проекте приложения GWT. Скорее всего вы что-то упустили.